# How to go a level up in MyClass.class.getResource()

Tags: java, uri

I want to add an Icon to my stage like this:

```
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image(MenuController.class.getResource("relativePath").toString()));
```

My structure is like this:

```
database
-icons
--myIcon.png
-gui
--MenuController.class
```

However, I don't know how to access the parent folder `database`.

I've tried `getClass().getResource("../icons/myIcon.png")` but`getResources()` returns null, probably because it can't resolve the URI.

But isn't "../" the right way to access the parent folder?

Thanks!

Comment: The `getResource` API doesn't support `..`. Use the absolute path to the resource.

Comment: Place the `icons` directory in the `gui` directory.  Then you can use `MenuController.class.getResource("icons/myIcon.png")`.  (And this just makes sense, considering icons are part of the GUI.)

Comment: @Slaw: does only getResource not support .. or also URI. Because I think I have read that URI does support it.

Comment: `URI`/`URL`/`Path`/`File` may all support it. However, the documentation of [`Class#getResource(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) and related methods make no mention of supporting `..`. Either the name doesn't start with a `/`, and thus is relative to the `Class`, or the name does start with a `/`, and thus is relative to the root of the classpath (i.e. absolute). Some of the API, such as `ClassLoader#getResource(String)`, only supports absolute paths (even when a leading `/` is not present).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the image from "root" resource `/database/icons/myIcon.png`:

```
 MenuController.class.getResource("/database/icons/myIcon.png")
```